# Matrix library for groovy

Tags: java, math, groovy

there is a matrix library for java available http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/  is there anything similar in groovy?

Comment: Since JAMA is Java, can't you just use it in Groovy?

Comment: just i was looking for a groovy implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could have a look at the **GroovyLab** or **Groovy-Matrix** projects covering classes for Groovy math engineering:

http://code.google.com/p/groovylab/

http://code.google.com/p/groovy-matrix/

both projects seem a bit outdated, but it should certainly be not a big problem to push them to the latest Groovy version.

Comment: its a wrapper around its java implementation

Answer (score 2):

You can easily use Java libraries inside Groovy code, just import and use. In addition, with a low effort, you could write your own DSL to wrap the JaMa library (and release it of course :)